# Get Alexa Rank using Firefix Addon

Tags: javascript

Now i have 2 ways of getting alexa rank using the API but i personally find that second method is better and easier without the use of xmlhttp.

1) using php but i got stuck at how to display this in Firefox sdk using javascript. Have try using xmlhttp but somehow there is error

```
<?php
$url = "https://www.google.com.my/?gws_rd=cr,ssl&ei=UCbJVMO-KZfe8AW-yYKICQ";
$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://data.alexa.com/data?cli=10&dat=snbamz&url='.$url);
$rank = isset($xml->SD[1]->POPULARITY)?$xml->SD[1]->POPULARITY->attributes()->TEXT:0;
$web = (string)$xml->SD[0]->attributes()->HOST;
$backlink = (int)$xml->SD[0]->LINKSIN->attributes()->NUM;

echo $rank;
?>
```

2) using request in javascript but there is an error saying that xml is not a function

```
var Request = require("sdk/request").Request;

var quijote = Request({     
    url: "http://data.alexa.com/data?cli=10&dat=snbamz&url=www.google.com",
    overrideMimeType: "application/xml; charset=latin1",
    onComplete: function (response) {
        xml = response.text;
        console.log(xml);
        var a = xml.getElementsByTagName("POPULARITY");
        console.log(xml[0].attributes[1].nodeValue);
    }
});
quijote.get();
```